# simple static server who return static files in rotation for every request

Tags: go

i have this simple server writed in golang :

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
        http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

I want add new function :
every request GET /rotate return one file content in rotation from /static folder.
for example in /static folder exist 7 file, for every request server return : file1, file2, file3 ...

How i can do this in go ?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried to implement this with?

Comment: @Adrian, no impemetantion code, i dont know from where start do this :(

Comment: Then this question is much too broad for SO. This is not a code-writing service. Do some research, attempt an implementation, and if you have trouble, post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple server that should get you started toward your goal. A couple of things to note about the implementation:

1. The file names are loaded only once during program startup. If a file disappears while the program is running, the server will return a 404 when it comes up in the rotation.
2. We need to use locking (in this case, via `sync.Mutex`) as each request will run in its own go routine.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    dir := flag.String("dir", ".", "directory of files to serve")
    flag.Parse()

    f, err := os.Open(*dir)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    files, err := f.Readdir(0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    filenames := make([]string, 0, len(files))
    for _, file := range files {
        if !file.IsDir() {
            filenames = append(filenames, file.Name())
        }
    }

    var (
        idxLock sync.Mutex
        idx     int
    )

    http.HandleFunc("/rotate", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if len(filenames) == 0 {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }

        idxLock.Lock()
        i := idx
        idx++
        if idx >= len(filenames) {
            idx = 0
        }
        idxLock.Unlock()

        http.ServeFile(w, r, filepath.Join(*dir, filenames[i]))
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```